# Small font size for ampersand

Tags: fontsize, ampersand

I want **&** symbol in small font size. But `\small{\&}` produces italicized ampersand symbol [like here](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~anuj/ampercend.jpg). How can I get the small fontsize **&** symbol?

**Edit**: figured out that, the italics was because of the theorem environment (from acm_proc_article-sp style). Is there any way to override italics only for & character?

Comment: Harish Kumar's answer is correct.  Hovever, I don't get the result you complain about in standard document.  The italics must be due to something else in your document.

Comment: I figured that the italics were because of the theorem environment, and have updated the question accordingly. The question is not the same duplicate anymore.

Comment: Turns out `\DeclareMathOperator{\amp}{\textup{\scriptsize \&}}` solves the problem. As question is now closed, I can not add this as answer.

Comment: Well, the question was originally a duplicate. If you change the meaning (such as "how to get an upright ampersand within italic text"), please do it clearly (no "Edit:" addition, reworded) including the title. Also consider, it it just a localized support question (fixed) or of good use for the public, i.e. a bit general (not just "how do I ... in acm_proc_article-sp ... in the case xy ... ). Then I'm convinced to reopen. ;-) But everybody feel free to cast a reopen vote.

Answer (score 5):

`\small` doesn't take an argument. Use it like `\small \&`. To make the effect local, put the entire thing inside braces like `{\small \&}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\Huge \& \huge \& \LARGE \& \large \& \normalsize \& \small \& \footnotesize \&  \scriptsize \& \tiny \&
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit

In math mode I get this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
E_{1} \& \text{\small\&} E_{2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If this is what you are not getting, then something else is going on in your code. Please try posting it so that we can play with it :-)

Comment: BTW I still get italicized & when I use this in math mode. I am not able to figure out why. How can I do this is math mode? I tried using both \mathrm and \textrm.

Comment: The problem was the theorem environment, which was italicizing the &. After google-ing I found that declaring & as binary operator, I can stop it from being italicized. So `\DeclareMathOperator{\amp}{\textup{\scriptsize \&}}` resolves my problem.

Comment: @anuj919 I don't think `\textup` is needed. If you enclose it inside as `\text{\&}`, then it is treated as normal text, hence won't be italicized.

Comment: Without \textup, it becomes italicized again. :)